# Is 'not' a modal verb?

Tags: verbs

In the following sentence, 'has' is an auxiliary verb and 'seen' is the main verb. What is the role of 'not'? Is it a verb?

*She has not seen the movie.*

Can you give some evidence about why *not* is or isn't a verb, and also why *not* is or isn't a modal verb?

Comment: On a site like this, this is the kind of question that deserves a decent answer with lots and lots of hard evidence.

Answer (score 1):

"Not" is not a verb. "Not" isn't really the same part of speech as any other word. It is unique. But if you have to classify it for some reason, it seems closest to an adverb. Dictionaries like classifying words by parts of speech, and that's the classification they use: e.g., the [American Heritage Dictionary](https://www.ahdictionary.com/word/search.html?q=not) or [Oxford Living Dictionaries](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/not).

This isn't a well-sourced answer. In general, dictionaries are not a reliable source for information about "parts of speech" from a linguistic point of view, because dictionary categorizations of the "part of speech" of words are often based on simplified or outdated models. I haven't read any linguistic sources that talk about whether *not* is a verb, but here are some arguments that I can come up with.

#### Evidence that "not" is not a finite verb form

It's easy to see that in standard English, we cannot replace a finite verb with *not*:

- She *wants* to see the movie. (grammatical)
- *She *not* to see the movie. (ungrammatical)
- She *seems* happy. (grammatical)
- *She *not* happy. (ungrammatical)

If *not* were some kind of verb, it would have to be a non-finite verb form. This makes it unlike the modal auxiliaries (*can will may* etc.), which characteristically have finite forms, but no non-finite forms.